# Python, Postgres, and integers with blank values?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I have some fairly sparse data columns where most of the values are blank but sometimes have some integer value. In Python, if there is a blank then that column is interpreted as a float and there is a .0 at the end of each number.

I tried two things:

- Changed all of the columns to text and then stripped the .0 from everything
- Filled blanks with 0 and made each column an integer

Stripping the .0 is kind of time consuming on about 2mil+ rows per day and then the data is in text format which means I can't do quick sums and stuff.

Filling blanks seems somewhat wasteful because some columns literally have just a few actual values out of millions. My table for just one month is already over 80gigs (200 columns, but many of the columns after about 30 or so are pretty sparse).

What postgres datatype is best for this? There are NO decimals because the columns contain the number of seconds and it must be pre-rounded by the application.

Edit - here is what I am doing currently (but this bloats up the size and seems wasteful):

```
def create_int(df, col):
    df[col].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
```

If I try to create the column astype(int) without filling in the 0s I get the error:

error: Cannot convert NA to integer

Here is the link the the Gotcha about this.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

So it makes each int a float. Should I change the datatypes in postgres to numeric or something? I do not need high precision because there are no values after the decimal.

Comment: These are null meaning no data exists. For example, a column might be the number of seconds an event was in a certain status. Since the status never occurred, this column has no data. Or it occurred for 0 seconds (if I use the fillna approach).

Comment: where do  you get your data columns from?

Comment: Since I am using Python to load the data (after modifying it with Pandas), I can't assign the column astype int if there are null values. Python creates a float. I can't load them into the database if the column is integer type because it will say something like 1440.0 does not match the expected datatype or something similar.

Comment: Can you create a little [mcve]?

Comment: Data columns are from a MS SQL database which is replicated for me. I query from this data and consolidate a few tables. I want to keep a full record of it though because they are replacing the data every few days  completely. This means that I have no control over the columns or normalization. The original columns are all nvarchar but it makes sense to convert them to numbers so I can do calculations and connect it to a visualization tool.

Comment: What would happen if you just wrapped it with a float and an int? That should pretty quickly convert text to float to int (even with lots of data.

Comment: Made an edit with my current process to fill 0s and the Gotcha passage from the docs which clearly shows exactly what is happening to my data. It casts the ints as floats. Will it make sense to change the column types in Postgres to numeric instead? What is most efficient?

Comment: Oscar, hm. Perhaps because I am trying to change a whole column in a pandas DataFrame? It might just be a limitation of pandas, perhaps, since they do not have an int representation of a null value so all ints are casted to floats.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the fact you are using POSTGRESQL (9.3 or above), and implement a "poor man's sparse row" by converting your data into Python dictionaries and then using a JSON datatype (JSONB is better).

The following Python snippets generate random data in the format you said you have yours, convert them to apropriate json, and upload them into a PostgreSQL table with a JSONB column.

```
import psycopg2
import json
import random

def row_factory(n=200, sparcity=0.1):
   return [random.randint(0, 2000) if random.random() < sparcity else None for i in range(n)]


def to_row(data):
    result = {}
    for i, element in enumerate(data):
        if element is not None: result[i] = element
    return result


def from_row(row, lenght=200):
    result = [None] * lenght
    for index, value in row.items():
        result[int(index)] = value
    return result


con = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://...")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE numbers (values JSONB)")

def upload_data(rows=100):
    for i in range(rows):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(%s)", (json.dumps(to_row(row_factory(sparcity=0.5))),) )

upload_data()

# To retrieve the sum of all columns:

cursor.execute("""SELECT {} from numbers limit 10""".format(", ".join("sum(CAST(values->>'{}' as int))".format(i) for i in range(200))))
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

It took me a while to find out how to perform numeric operations on the JSONB data inside Postgresql (if you will be using them from Python you can just use the snippet `from_row` function above). But the last two lines have a Select operation that performs a SUM on all columns - the select statement itself is assembled using Python string formatting methods - the key to use a Json value as number is to select it with the  `->>` operator, and them cast it to number.(the  `sum(CAST(values->>'0' as int))` part)